# whats the best way to handle ng-include not found?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have page which includes a file dynamically like so:

```
<div ng-include="filename + '.html'"><div>
```

This works if the file exists. Otherwise it throws a big ugly console error.

Is there an elegant way to handle this in angular? e.g. something like:

```
<div ng-include="'somefile.html'" ng-ifnexist="'default-page.html'"></div>
```

Whats the best approach?

Answer (score 1):

This is getting a bit messy, and ngIf is effectivly deprecated in favour of Directives, but what about

```
<div ng-if="[list of possible names].indexOf(filename) > -1">    
  <div ng-include="filename + '.html'" ></div>
</div>

<div ng-if="[list of possible names].indexOf(filename) == -1">    
  <div ng-include="'default-page.html'" ></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. However, in my case I don't know necessarily know the [list of possible names]. Maybe it's a security issue